# How to remove others bin in a dc.js row chart

Tags: dc.js

I want to remove "Others" bin in the row chart and bar chart. How to do this using d3 or dc.js.

Comment: Not sure how you have implemented "others" for your bar chart, but for the row chart, shouldn't [`.othersGrouper(false)`](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CapMixin.html#othersGrouper__anchor) work?